# Catching ResultSet.next()'s exception

Tags: scala, jdbc, resultset

I have a forward only cursor. Due to some issues, fetching specific columns on some rows might throw an exception (proprietary driver, the exception is due to encoding actually).

So how to catch such exception in this code (Scala code):

```
while(rs.next){
    println(rs.getString("column"))
}
```

I've tried `while(true)` with a try/catch block inside, but apparently after the exception is thrown, I can't move the cursor no matter what. The exception is thrown when calling `.next()` method.

Comment: if the while(true) option is not working, it's the driver that has to be fixed. Even if you catch the exception, the driver's ResultSet implementation gets "corrupted"

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `scala.util.control.Exception`. For example:

```
scala> import scala.util.control.Exception._
import scala.util.control.Exception._

scala> def div2(by: Int) = catching(classOf[ArithmeticException]) opt (2 / by)
div2: (by: Int)Option[Int]

scala> div2(2)
res23: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> div2(0)
res24: Option[Int] = None
```

Comment: Knowing this wouldn't work because of the point Bozho mentioned, I gave it a try just for sake of learning more about the `control` package. I did `while (true){catching(classOf[com.foo.BarException]) opt (rs.next) }` And the results were interesting, it caught the exception and outputted the same row for exactly 8 times after the exception was thrown.